# Will JOSE4J Support JWKS key validation through the OpenID Connect discovery document

Tags: jwt, jose4j, jwk

JOSE4J takes the jwks_uri as its starting point for JWT validation and I wondered whether it would be possible to support the Discovery Document as the starting point and JOSE4J would pick up the jwks_uri from there and then go the the JWKS key document to pick the public key matching the JWT at had through the kid. This way I only have to hardcode the discovery document uri in my code, as I worry a bit whether the jwks_uri might change without notice, the wellknow discovery document is to my knowledge fixed.

This is how it works now:

```
    // The HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver uses JWKs obtained from the HttpsJwks and will select the
    // most appropriate one to use for verification based on the Key ID and other factors provided
    // in the header of the JWS/JWT.
    HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver httpsJwksKeyResolver = 
       new HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver(https_jwks);
```

Maybe it would be nice to have the resolver recognize whether the discovery document uri is passed in or not and behave accordingly.

Thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct support for it but you could implement your own `VerificationKeyResolver` with that logic (would likely use `HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver` internally). Or the application code could (periodically) pull the jwks_uri value from discovery document and use it to create the `HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver`.